# Can Someone Destroy Sessions From The Browser?

Tags: php, session

Basically, I have a script that will count the number of failed attempts to do something. If the number is higher than 5 I will block the `IP Address` for 15 minutes.

The question is after the first failed attempt the counter will equal to 1 then 2 .. 5

Can someone from his machine destroy all the sessions that has been saved in the browser or not? I am talking about `$_SESSION` not `COOKIES`

If yes I will try to consider changing the way of counting from sessions, and storing the values in my local files.

Comment: If the user closes the browser and opens it again and browse to your page a new session is created. Also if the user clears the session cookies, new session is created. So no meaning in using session in your situation.

Comment: @Echo then how do you think the session is created at server end?

Comment: bansi is correct about his first comment...take example of facebook simple

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can Someone Destroy Sessions From The Browser?

**No.** Sessions are a server-side construct. Sessions are not stored in the browser.

However, HTTP is a stateless protocol, which means that the client must identify itself, every time it issues a request, in order to be associated with its session. Typically this is done using a cookie.

Users can delete or modify their cookies, so it's entirely possible for an adversarial client to get a "fresh" session each time they query your server. In general, **there is no attack-proof way to do what you want!**

This is why, for example, Stack Exchange requires users to sign in before allowing them to cast votes. Otherwise they could cast multiple votes just by deleting cookies, changing IP address, etc. which SE designers really, really don't want you to do. However requiring user accounts are *still* not bulletproof because you could just [create more than one!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/sock-puppets/info)

Of course, you're hardly the first person to face this issue:

- [Limiting failed logins](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=limit%20failed%20logins)
- [Preventing multiple voting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prevent%20vote)

Comment: To add to that: someone can also destroy the session by closing and reopening their browser.

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox only for session cookies. There are other types of cookies which are not removed when the browser is closed.

Comment: @MattBall depending on cookies is not useful, what if no cookie is used by browser?

Comment: @MattBall - Right but the question was about sessions in particular.

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox a [session cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie) is not the same thing as "a cookie which contains a session id."

Comment: @MattBall - Think we're having a circular discussion about the same thing. I'm referring to the content you access through `$_SESSION`, which utilizes a session cookie, which is destroyed (usually) when you close your browser.

Comment: @Loïc how is that helpful? If there is no session ID (that is, the user deleted their cookie) there is no way for the server to correctly distinguish the malicious user from well-meaning new users.

Comment: That's the name of the cookie which usually contains the session_id.

Comment: @Loïc again, I don't see how that's helpful. Please elaborate.

Comment: @MattBall Thank's, There are several ways to limit failed logins or multiple votes. 

However, what if someone tries to write a program that will open your login page and try usernames from the site and RANDOM passwords, and run this program for days, they will lock all the accounts, and may find a matched username and password correct? This way may limit the person's IP from trying more than five times. 

The blocking process is from the database, but the checking process can be from the sessions or database or local files. That's why I asked this question. BIG THANKS

Comment: @Othman captchas are a fairly effective tool against that sort of attack.